# pgfkeys undefined control sequence

Tags: mactex, pgfkeys

I recently upgraded to MacTeX 2023, and am experiencing this warning when using a custom library (https://github.com/slithy/rpg_module):

```
640: Undefined control sequence.
l.1640 \pgfutil@protected
                         \def\pgfmathprintnumber{%
? 
))
```

The error doesn't happen with MacTeX 2019. After experimenting, I was able to narrow it down to this minimum example using vanilla LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\input{pgfutil-common}
\input{pgfmath.code}

\begin{document}

Test document

\end{document}
```

That document causes the same warning. If I comment out `\input{pgfmath.code}`, the error goes away.

Anyone know what's going on here? The library I'm using also has those two input lines in that order. I don't know if removing that second input is actually the proper fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `pgfrcs` as well as `pgfkeys` for `pgfmath`. It would be better by far to load the `pgfmath` package.

That is, it would be better to use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}

Test document

\end{document}
```

This way, if the dependencies change, your code won't break (unless there's a package bug, of course). Individual components of pgf aren't designed to be `\input` with impunity. That said, `pgfmath`'s dependencies haven't changed: `pgfrcs` was required as well as `pgfkeys` in the version I have from TeX Live 2019.